# How to use GWT emulation classes?

Tags: gwt, emulation

I am developing a GWT app and I would like to improve the performance of string building.  I would like to use the StringBuffer provided by GWT, but I am not sure how to access it.  I already have the gwt-user.jar, and it looks like the emul sources are inside, but how can I use them in my IDE(eclipse)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The emulated sources are the replacement for real Java implementations. They are used all the time, i.e., when you write `java.lang.StringBuilder` in your GWT client code, GWT actually substitutes the emulated class from `gwt-user.jar/super/com/google/gwt/emul/java/lang.

Basically, you just need to use whatever you want to use, as you would use it in Java, and an emulated class will be substituted as necessary. Of course, limitations apply: if it is not implemented in the emulated GWT code, you can't use it (`String.format` is an example).